# how to use shortcut key id different forms that grouped in one tool strip menu

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

If I click invoke all toolstrip menu then only these four forms display(my forms: car Retrieval, keylocation, RetrievalAlert, Car Delivery confirmation). I grouped together these four forms in one click.

Code is like this:

```
private void InvloveAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyUp += HandleKeyPress; frmKeyAssignBoard frm = new frmKeyAssignBoard();
    frm.Location = new Point(625, 0); frm.MdiParent = this; frm.KeyUp += HandleKeyPress; frm.Show(); FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest frm1 = new FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest();
    frm1.Location = new Point(625, 225);
    frm1.MdiParent = this;
    frm.KeyUp += HandleKeyPress;
    frm1.Show();
    FrmDelivary frm2 = new FrmDelivary();
    frm2.Location = new Point(965, 0);
    frm2.MdiParent = this;
    frm.KeyUp += HandleKeyPress;
    frm2.Show();
    frmCarCall frm3 = new frmCarCall();
    frm3.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    frm3.MdiParent = this;
    frm.KeyUp += HandleKeyPress;
    frm3.Show();
}
```

Actually these forms are child forms of my master forms. I want to use function keys in these form.

I mean if I click 'k' that should locate cursor to keylocation form - carid textbox, and if I click 'D' that should locate cursor to retreval alert - driver id gridview row, if I click 'R',then it should locate cursor to car retrieval - car id textbox. How can I do this?

i try to write your code in my master key down event like this:
  Private Sub frmMaster_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
            Dim form As New FrmDelivary
            form.Show()
            form.txtTicket.Focus()
            Cursor.Position = form.txtTicket.Location
        End If
    End Sub
if i click A nothing happening

Comment: Just a note, delivery is spelled 'Delivery' not 'delivary'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the Focus to the specific control and setting the cursor position. I wrote a bit of code that opens another form on the KeyDown event and sets the focus to a specific textbox. Of course to reference a control on one form from another one I had to make the control public. Not sure exactly how yours is set up with the multiple forms and how they're linked together, but if you can reference the control, you can set the focus to it.

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
            form.NotesTextBox.Focus();
            Cursor.Position = form.NotesTextBox.Location;
        }
```

Comment: Whichever one has the focus. This code is for opening a new instance of Form2 from Form1 in my program and focusing on a particular textbox. If you already have an instance of Form2 open you'll have to do it somewhat differently. But to answer your question, the focus and cursor position are the things you're looking for. Also, in the gridview, you'd have to set the current cell like `datagridview1.CurrentCell = whichever cell you want to select; datagridview1.CurrentCell.Selected = true;`